# How to Blur the background until a function execute in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to blurring the background and a Messagebox initialize with "Please wait until sync finished". I have to start this Messagebox when I call the webapiConnection and close when the updates finished. 
is it possible in WP8?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve this problem using customMessagebox. If you create a customMessagebox then you can use show() and Dismiss() functions to start the popup display and close it. When this customMessagebox opens the background going to be blur.